# Visual Studio 2015 Diagnostic Tools Memory Usage & C++ Debugging

Tags: c++, memory, visual-studio-2015, debug-diagnostic-tool

I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and a native C++ project. I would like to analyze memory usage. Our software runs as a Windows service, so I typically debug by attaching to the running service. I found that when I do that the Diagnostic Tools Memory Usage is not available:

[image]

However, when I start the software through the debugger (by pressing F5) the Memory Usage tool shows up:

[image]

**Is it supposed to be like that, ie. is the Memory Usage Diagnostic Tool not supported when attaching to a process?**

The Memory Usage Diagnostic Tool is missing both when attaching to a locally running process as well as when remote debugging (attaching to a process on another machine).

Answer (score 2):

The Diagnostic Tools native memory profiler will support attaching to a process in the upcoming Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.  There will be a CTP preview release coming out this Fall that you can try out.

Comment: Here is link to the Update 1 download that now supports profiling via attach to process: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx